# How to retrieve curl code, using pycurl python3

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

In c/c++, the return value of curl_easy_perform() is a curl code that tells you information, 0 on success etc. In python perform() corresponds to curl_easy_perform() as stated in documentation, but i do not see anything talking about how I can retrieve a CURLcode from a response.

Comment: You would get an exception if the call fails.

Comment: yes and that exception contains the code, BUT there is no "right" way to get it without string splitting etc

Comment: The code is exposed, see http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/callbacks.html#error-reporting